# API Gateway proxy to lambda test works but not endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I have an API gateway that invokes a lambda function using proxy integration. The lambda handler is like this:

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
   # TODO implement
   return {
     'statusCode': 200,
     'body': json.dumps(my_func(event["queryStringParameters"]["level"]))

   }
```

When I hit test on the API gateway and pass a param level=easy, the function runs correctly and I see the output in json. However when I take the invoke URL that is shown under stages and run it from the browser

https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/myendpoint?level=easy

It errors out like this:

```
   {"errorMessage": "'queryStringParameters'", 
    "errorType": "KeyError", "stackTrace": 
    [["/var/task/lambda_function.py", 95, "lambda_handler", "'body' : json.dumps(get_puzzle(event[\"queryStringParameters\"][\"level\"]))"]]}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you still having the issue?. Did you deploy your latest API changes to stage and run again?.